# Foreign key in serializer is not json serializable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a serializer that points to two different objects from `Account` and `Currency`, but when its called i keep getting following error: `TypeError: Object of type 'Account' is not JSON serializable`. what am i doing wrong?

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('user', 'currency', 'task', 'deposit_amount', 'receive_amount')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = Account.objects.only('id').get(id=validated_data['user'])
            currency = Currency.objects.only('id').get(id=validated_data['currency'])
            return Invoice.objects.create(
                user=user,
                currency=currency,
                task=validated_data['task'],
                deposit_amount=validated_data['deposit_amount'],
                receive_amount=validated_data['receive_amount']
            )
```

**data from request**

```
{'currency': 2, 'task': 1, 'deposit_amount': 1.005, 'receive_amount': 62793.51, 'user': 23}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume from the `serializers.ModelSerializer` that this is using the Django REST Framework.

In this case you are dealing with a nested model and you want to display both the 'main' model: the `Invoice`, as well as the related `Currency` and `Account` models.

Django REST Framework has [multiple ways of dealing with nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

It seems only the ID's need to be displayed (not the actual data of the objects. This can be done in DRF with a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    currency = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    user = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('user', 'currency', 'task', 'deposit_amount', 'receive_amount')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
```

This *might* also automatically fetch the `currency` and `user` instances, or a `queryset` attribute on the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` has to be set for that. It's quite hard to find documentation / examples on this which do not use `SomeModel.queryset.all()`, so you will have to experiment with that yourself.

Comment: looks great but in this case of the `create` u avoided the `user` is that on purpose?

Comment: @PeterPik No reason, I overlooked it I suppose.

Comment: and the `Currency` object already exists so what is the reason for creating a new? and i think the whole problem is related to the `Account` object

Comment: Ah yes, I really need to learn how to read. I'll update the answer. The answer remains the same though: Tell your `InvoiceSerializer` how it can serialize the `user` (`Account`) object.

Comment: i've added snippet of the post request data. I'm not sure why i need to serialize when all i have is the `id` of the `Account` and `Currency` object. why cant i just find the object using `get()` and then set it in my new `Invoice` objects. or would it make sense just to save id´s then?

Comment: @PeterPik Updated the answer. Your create function should still work fine, otherwise you could play around a bit with the `queryset` attribute on the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.